# How do i make round bottle look more cubic with really soft edges?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials

I am a complete beginer. I was trying to model this 5 liter bottle and then realized it supposed be more squire - like in the included image. How do i do it? No way i can figure it out myself...
I know this model is a mess and not perfectly modeled but it'll do for my purposes. Just need it a little bit squared like in the image... [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Start with an octagon
- <kbd>W</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> Subdivide  a copy of it
- Make another copy, and <kbd>S</kbd> scale its orthogonal vertices in to make it squarer.
- Make a copy of that, and subdivide it, too.
- With the copy, instead of subdividing it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>bevel all its vertices.

When making the variations, they won't be side by side as illustrated: shift them up in Z to keep them out of the way, and vertically lined up. You can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> make copies of those to work with, any time you like.

[image]

You now have all the profiles you will need for your bottle, bar a bit of tweaking.

Now assemble the bottle vertically, working your way down by  <kbd>E</kbd> sometimes extruding from copies of your profiles, and sometimes using  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>E</kbd> > 'Bridge Edge Loops' between them.

You can use the shipped add-on Loop Tools > circle to make the profile circular at the neck.

The profiles shown here are: the neck, just above the ridge, and the smooth label area.

The closer the vertices on the profile are to one another, the sharper the crease in the final surface, after subdivision. You can vary the bevel on the squarer profile to achieve that. This example has 2 levels of Catmull-Clark, in a  Subdivision modifier, and the profiles are shown with the subdivision.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I call job well done with this bottle of mine (don't know how to post a picture of the result though) Still have to figure out few things - material for the liquid inside and modeling the plactic handle... So much work for just one bottle :)